# solaris os setting path and environment variables

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables, solaris

in my solaris university account I'm setting path using setenv like setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/j2se
the path gets created and gets recognised recognized. But the moment I logout and login again these all environment variables and paths are forgotten. Why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's per session only. You have to save it to file like ~/.cshrc or ~/.bash_profile:

```
$ echo 'setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/j2se' >> ~/.cshrc
```

Comment: then set it with `setenv` in the file I mentioned.

Comment: there's no such file. but there's a file like .cshrc how to set path in that ?

Comment: $ echo 'setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/j2se' >> ~/.cshrc